# argument unused during compilation: '-fuse-ld=lld'

Tags: linker, clang, lld

I have successfully built *clang* and *lld* from source, and both are now available under my *.../llvm-project/build/bin* directory.

Following [lld documentation](https://lld.llvm.org/), I am now trying to pass *-fuse-ld=lld* command line directive to *clang* to force it to use *lld* instead of system's default linker (which is *GNU ld* if I am not mistaken) as follows:

```
../llvm-project/build/bin/clang -fuse-ld=lld -c test.c
```

But I get this warning:

```
clang-16: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fuse-ld=lld' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

Which I suppose means *lld* was not used as the linker despite me asking for it.

What am I doing wrong?

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 and I am using clang version 16.0.0 and lld 16.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

This: `clang -fuse-ld=lld -c test.c` is a *compilation* command. It does not perform *any* linking.

This argument: `-fuse-ld=lld` is telling the compiler driver which linker to use *at link time*.

You told the driver:

1. to *not* do linking (the `-c` argument) and
2. to use `lld` for linking in the same command

The driver has no choice but to *ignore* your second instruction, since it's *not going* to do any linking, and that's what the warning is all about.

You can safely ignore this warning, but a better solution is to pass the `-fuse-ld=lld` argument *only* to the link stage, and not to any compile stages.

Comment: With CMake: use the [`LINK_OPTIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_OPTIONS.html) (supersedes `LINK_FLAGS`).